# Site rápido quando acesso pelo IP, mas super lento via Domain Name

Tags: ip, dns

Estou tendo um problema que ao acessar meu servidor VPS usando o IP, o acesso é imediato mas quando acesso usando HTTP, a pagina chega a demorar 10 segundos para abrir, fiz alguns testes na minha máquina local e esse foi o resultado

(Imagem 1): [image: Imagem comparando IP e Dominio]

Fiz um acesso via VNC no servidor pra testar e o problema é o mesmo acessando as páginas de dentro do próprio servidor(Imagem2):

[image: Imagem de comparação entre IP e dominio de dentro do servidor]

O suporte da hostinger apenas afirma que o problema é com algum script no meu site mas sei que não é porque senão daria problema usando o endereço IP.
 Fiz o ping tanto usando IP quanto domínio e o resultado é o mesmo, ou seja, o servidor está respondendo aos pings muito bem em ambos os casos.

Alguém tem idéia do que poderia estar acontecendo? Estou usando ubuntu 16.04, kernel 4 com Apache 2

Comment: Amigo, aonde você esta fazendo a resolução de nomes? ou seja, DNS? em qual empresa esta alocado o seu domínio? Na sua rede. seu computador passa direto pro modem? ou tem roteador? esta me parecendo problemas de DNS. –

Comment: Então, estou usando o hostinger, o que me bugou de vez agora é que o subdominio loja.zenycosta.com está funcionando perfeito assim como o IP 153.92.208.69/loja

Comment: Amigo, tem alguns pontos para se verificar, como você sabe que esta funcionando perfeitamente? se o problema esta quando utiliza o nome resolvido, verifique o servidor DNS, veja a rota como esta configurada, veja as configurações do seu domínio, e logo adianto hostinger fuja.

Answer (score 2):

RESOLVIDO

Descobri algo aqui quE resolveu, um dos meus css estavam sendo gerados dinamicamente e depois de gerados, eu o inseria na pagina usando file_get_contents($CSS_Gerado_Dinamicamente_com_PHP), não sei o motivo mas ao acessar usando o IP, tanto o css era gerado dinamicamente normalmente quanto o file-get_content() também funcionava normalmente, mas quando eu acessava pelo nome do domínio, alguma coisa fazia ou o CSS não ser gerado imediatamente ou o file-get_content() não funcionava, ainda não consegui entender a conexão entre isso e isso não consegui resolver, a alternativa foi criar um css estático a partir do css que era criado dinamicamente, executei o código:

-arquivo.css.php-

```
<?php
$CSS_Estatico = '../cache/headline.css';
if (file_exists($CSS_Estatico)) {
    include($CSS_Estatico);
    exit;
}
ob_start();

--Meu Código CSS--

$cached = fopen($CSS_Estatico, 'w');
fwrite($cached, ob_get_contents());
fclose($cached);
ob_end_flush(); // Send the output to the browser
?>
```

assim quando eu executo o `file-get_content(../cache/CSS_Estatico.css)` dentro da minha , tudo funciona perfeitamente, eu sei que não faz o menor sentido pq se o problema fosse no css que é criado dinamicamente, o problema aconteceria ao acessar direto pelo IP também.

Aí tive apenas que modificar meu CMS pra toda vez que eu postar algo novo, ele recria esse CSS estático como se fosse um cache.

Se alguém souber onde está a conexão entre meu CSS dinâmico e o problema da lentidão quando se usa o nome de domínio, fiquem à vontade pra deixar a teoria do que poderia ser pa quem tiver o mesmo problema.

Te toda forma obrigado pelas dicas e PROBLEMA RESOLVIDO

PS.(A hostinger é terrível pra dar algum suporte, nunca conseguiram me ajudar em nada e nunca conheci ninguém que conseguiu algum ajuda deles)

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVIDO 2

A solução que dei acima foi uma alternativa ao problema real mas achei a  solução ao problema original, se alguém tiver o mesmo problema, eu resolvi assim:

-Configurei o DNS pelo bind 9 e o problema principal foi resolvido, agora tanto o acesso via Domain Name quanto via IP está legal, ambos com a mesma velocidade independente dos meu arquivos serem estáticos ou dinâmicos.